# Prevent click without function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Today I was pseudo-coding a we and then I tried to make a hide/show content function for mobile browser.

The problem is (not my hardcoded thing), it's the delay of the button to hide or show content and I think it's because it's not previously initialized.

HTML:

```
<article id="horarios">
 <h2>Horarios <a onclick="showContent(parentNode.parentNode.id, this.id)" class="showContentBtn" id="showContentBtnHr">&#xe808;</a></h2>
  <span id="hide-horarios">
```

About my hardcode thing I just make that "parent, parent id" (Horarios) concat with "hide-", I don't know a better solution now but in some way it's ok.

Now here's the problem:

JS:

```
    function showContent(value, value2){
      var value="hide-"+value;
      var content = document.getElementById(value).style.display;
      if(content == "none"){
        document.getElementById(value).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById(value2).innerHTML = "&#xe809;";
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById(value).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(value2).innerHTML = "&#xe808;";
      }
    }
```

CSS

```
#hide-programas, #hide-horarios, #hide-aboutus{
  display: none;
}
```

When I test it, I have to click one time and it do nothing then it works.
I think this is because "content" not have any value on it to compare so there's nothing to do the first time and then it have a value.

It's possible to fix it? I know it will hurt your eyes but this weird sh*t works in some way.

Comment: It's because `.style.display` returns an empty string the first time, as it's not set.

Comment: @adeneo Sorry, I forgot to add the CSS code. In the CSS code the "hide-horarios" is set display:"none";.

Comment: That doesn't help at all, it still returns an empty string unless the style is set inline, just try it.

Comment: You can't use `parentNode.parentNode.id` unless you've initialised a global *parentNode* variable, perhaps you mean `this.parentNode.parentNode.id`. And why would you do that just to get the ID so you can call *getElementById*, why not just pass the elements? `showContent(this.parentNode.parentNode, this)` then just use *el0* and *el1* in the function, removing all those redundant *document.getElementById* calls.

Comment: @adeneo It's **crazy**! I tried with visibility and it "worked" the space remains the text is gone but when I tried to add to display it stopped working. Then I remember about you said nothing on it and just put a "" as condition, so it worked. Thanks! You prevent me spend the night doing this.

Comment: @RobG I never used DOM JS so thanks for the advice, I don't initialize the node ParentNode as global but I can use it's just convention or syntax? I think if I pass a lot of getElementById vars it will be worse to read in some way (You make me think it). _el0_? _el1_? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Referencing elements by their position in the DOM isn't a good idea since if you change the structure your code stops working. Since the IDs you want are based on the ID of the element that's clicked on, you can just pass *this* from the listener and go from there. Then use *getElementById* once for each other element you need to access and store them in variables.

Comment: @RobG Now I understand, thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best fixed by hiding and showing using a class rather than direct access to DOM properties. Below is just a brief example,  e.g.

```js
function toggleClass(id, className) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el && el.classList && el.classList.toggle) {
    el.classList.toggle(className);
  }
}
```

```html
<head><style type="text/css">
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
</style></head>

<body>
  <div class="hidden" id="d0">I'm a div</div>
  <button onclick="toggleClass('d0','hidden')">Toggle div</button>
</body>
```

It's not too hard to support browsers that don't support the *classList* object if you need to go back that far (IE 9 and lower).

Comment: Nah, forgot about IE. Because the web uses HTML5 audio tag and flexbox and I already use Modernizr for that. Thanks for the reply +1.

Answer (score 0):

### Why doesn't it work?

Your Javascript gets the element's style **directly from the its HTML**, so it is trying to read the contents of `display` style from the HTML `hide-horarios` element. However, at the start, this isn't set - you've defined the style in your CSS, as far as Javascript sees it, the **`style` attribute does not exist**, and thus neither does the `display` style.

Instead, it is set to `null`.

So, what happens when we click the button the first time? Well, there is no style element yet (it doesn't exist in the HTML markup), so the `content` variable is set to `null` (as there is no value). So, your `if` statement is then running a condition which becomes `if (null == "none")` - of course, we know that that will evaluate to `true`, so it runs the `else` part of your code, which **sets the display style to `none`**. This now means that the `style` attribute has been created, and that the display style inside of that has been set (by Javascript).

Next time the function runs, `style.display` will not be `null`, but instead `none`. So, your code will run as intended.

### What can we do?

There are a few solutions to your problem. Here I will discuss four:

1. Add the `style` attribute to your `<span id="hide-horarios">` element like so:

   ```
    <span id="hide-horarios" style="display:none">
   ```

   This is the most obvious solution, and works because the style attribute is now defined so it can be read with Javascript.
2. Read the **computed style of the element** rather than the value from the `style` attribute. This will pick up the style value that you set in your CSS file, so that you don't have to use inline styles.

   Simply change

   ```
   var content = document.getElementById(value).style.display;
   ```

   to

   ```
   var content = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(value))["display"];
   ```
3. Use an HTML5 data attribute to store information about wether the element is hidden or shown. This is probably semantically the best solution. Firstly, add the data attribute to your HTML element:

   ```
    <span id="hide-horarios" data-hidden="yes">
   ```

   Next, check the `data-hidden` attribute in your Javascript, instead of the style attribute:

   ```
   var content = document.getElementById(value).getAttribute("data-hidden");
   ```

   Now, you can check that. If you're using this solution, ensure that you check for your `data-hidden` value instead of `none` in your `if` statement - this can be anything that you want. In this example, we would do:

   ```
   if (content == "yes") {
       ...
   }
   ```

   Finally, we'll need to set the data attribute after each change. We can do this by running the following code in the `if` and `else` statements respectively:

   ```
   document.getElementById(value).setAttribute("data-hidden","no") //goes in if statement
   ```

   and

   ```
   document.getElementById(value).setAttribute("data-hidden","yes") //goes in else statement
   ```
4. Or, just simply flip around the `if` statement conditional:

   ```
   if (content != "block") {
       ...
   }
   ```

   (thanks to @nnnnnn in the comments)

Comment: The style **object** exists, however its *display* property hasn't been set. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, **adeneo** told me it in the comments of the principal post like you said there's no information to JS. And I tried (and it worked) just:

if(content == "none" || content == "")

I think it's the best solution and prevents the inline code (I hate it haha).

Comment: @RobG That's what I meant, I was just rushing to answer the question :P Fixing it now.